# how to get the value of JLabel in some other class

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel

I set the value of JLabel in class1

```
 NewLabel.setText("xyz");
```

I can read the value of Jlabel
    using

```
 NewLabel.getText();
```

and now I want to know How to Get the value of JLabel in Class2 using button click

```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){}
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) , SO isn't code generator,

Comment: Learn [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) and basic [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) first, you will get your answer real soon, I PROMISE :-)

Answer (score 2):

In class 1 create a method that returns the text of NewLabel (you can do this by putting the NewLabel's text in a String object,say str,and then return str).

Now in class 2 ,create an object of class 1,(e.g. Class1 cl1=new Class1();).Now simply call that method you created in class 1(e.g.,cl1.getNewLabelText()) .getNewLabelText() is a sample name you can give to your method created for class 1.